# importing the full data of excel file to a python script

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python tkinter to create a program that import excel file and plot the data of this file.

Let us say that the excel file contains the following data:

```
1           2

2           4

3           6

4           8 

5           10

6           12

7           14 

8           16

9           18
```

I used `pd.read_excel` function to read the data of this excel file and plot them later.

however, if I print the data using a simple `print (data)` function
the data will appear like this:

```
      1           2

0     2           4

1     3           6

2     4           8 

3     5           10

4     6           12

5     7           14 

6     8           16

7     9           18
```

The function that I used to do that is:

```
data = pd.read_excel(excel_filename)
print (data)
```

I tried to plot them but two curves appeared instead of one curve because it considered the first and second column (for the first curve) and the first and third column (for the second curve)

I tried to specify the the second and third column using the DataFrame but this one also have some problems. I used the following code to do that:

```
x=pd.DataFrame(data, columns= [1])
y=pd.DataFrame(data, columns= [2])
print("X: ", x)
print("Y: ", y)
```

The data using the above code is correct but the first row is disappeared which means that the data will be :

```
2           4

3           6

4           8 

5           10

6           12

7           14 

8           16

9           18
```

Any help!

Answer (score 0):

read_excel expects the first row in the file to be the header. That is the reason you are seeing it that way. Try this instead...

```
data = pd.read_excel(excel_filename, header=None)
```